# Magento 2 404 Not Found

Tags: magento2, nginx, 404

Fron my test server I can access files from: 
`http://127.0.0.1/magento222/testfile.php`

But my companies server has shows me this restricting message

[image]

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

In your magento nginx config add file name as below:

```
# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503|testfile)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Run below command:

```
service nginx restart
```

Comment: Is there a specific location that I have to put the file in or can It be in the root folder?

Comment: It be in your root folder but you need to give reference in your server etc/config.d/your host config file so magento will fetch configration from your root nginx.config file